# Angularjs .then function creating a var to pass outside .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, dynamic, dependency-injection

Is there a way to get the data from results out from the .then promise?

I know what i have posted is wrong, is there a way to do it?

this directive is for checking if the user exists on the database, i have made up errors in the check_username.php to send out type=1 when it finds it, if it doesn't then it will return a 2. what i'm trying to do is that display a 404 page or the actual profile page if found. thats basically what im trying to accomplish in that function is just finding if the user exists or not and displaying either the profile page or the 404 and sends the var to "templateUrl" to place the template in the profile page. Is there a better way of doing this?

```js
app.directive('profileDirective',function($http, $stateParams){

 var promise=$http.post('../../api/functions/check_username.php', JSON.stringify($stateParams.u) );
    
  promise.then(function(msg){
   if(msg.data.type=='2'){
    results = 'responses/404.php';
   }
   else if (msg.data.type=='1') {
    results = 'partials/profile/tpl/profile.head.tpl.php?u=' + $stateParams.u;
   }
  });

 console.log(results);

});
```

Would really be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: To be honnest, I cannot see any usecase where this would be a good idea. When you are doing asynchronous javascript, you have to stick with asynchronous javascript. Depending on what you want to do, there should be a way to do it asynchronously.

Comment: if I understand what you're asking, wouldnt a declaration of `var result;` before the `promise` declaration work?

Comment: i think you could do it, but u'd have to emit an event in the promise body, and then catch it few lines later in your directive body. That would look like u can access it there, but i have to agree with Clément, that would be a weird way of doing things.

Comment: You can **return** the result to **chain** it to another `.then` function but you can't get it "out" to the fiber (lightweight thread) that created the promise. `.then` functions always execute on a different fiber. However you can **chain** those fibers. What are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us that, we can help you.

Comment: this directive is for checking if the user exists on the database, i have made up errors in the check_username.php to send out type=1 when it finds it, if it doesn't then it will return a 2. what i'm trying to do is that display a 404 page or the actual profile page if found. thats basically what im trying to accomplish in that function is just finding if the user exists or not and displaying either the profile page or the 404 and sends the var to "templateUrl" to place the template in the profile page. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

As someone already stated, you just make a variable in scope of your directive.

```js
app.directive('profileDirective',function($http, $stateParams){

    var result;
 var promise=$http.post('../../api/functions/check_username.php', JSON.stringify($stateParams.u) );
    
  promise.then(function(msg){
   if(msg.data.type=='2'){
    result= 'responses/404.php';
   }
   else if (msg.data.type=='1') {
    result= 'partials/profile/tpl/profile.head.tpl.php?u=' + $stateParams.u;
   }
  });

 console.log(result);

});
```

Comment: this will return undefined when consoled out